# Newtonsoft.Json: Flatten generic reference property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The easiest way to explain this is by showing examples, so that's what I'll start with:

I have three objects:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FooString { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarInt { get; set; }
}

public class Message<T>
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set }
}
```

When deserializing to JSON, `Message<Foo>` becomes

```
{
    "subject": "FooSubject",
    "value": {
        "fooString": "abc"
    }
}
```

and `Message<Bar>` becomes

```
{
    "subject": "BarSubject",
    "value": {
        "barInt": 123
    }
}
```

Is there any way to merge the inner generic object into the Message using Newtonsoft.JSON? Or is there another way to merge two C# classes into the same JSON object? Meaning the end result for Message would look like this:

```
{
    "subject": "FooSubject",
    "fooString": "abc"
}
```

This could of course end up with naming conflicts, but that's easy to avoid in my case. I don't want to handle it using inheritance because a Foo/Bar is not always a Message, but a message will contain one of them.

Another thing is that the generic object might contain other objects which I do *not* want to flatten.

Thanks!

Comment: This is *mapping* one model to another and is best done with tools like AutoMapper. Json.NET is a serializer, not a mapper. In general, an API's message model won't be the same as the domain model used by the service. The models should be able to evolve independently. You can't do that easily if you try to map one to the other during serialization'

Comment: I understand your point, but I only use these classes as objects containing data. This was just an example, the real case I'm working with is finance-related and the classes are Position<T> where T will be financial instruments such as Option, Equity, IRS. These objects are then never really mapped into domain objects (other than what my post is about), but the data is used for calculations.

However, I feel that this isn't my strongest subject. Do you happen to know of any articles or books which explain this kind of modelling well?

Comment: That's precisely the point. Your JSON output is your API signature/application contract. It shouldn't change if your DTOs change. BTW `the data is used for calculations` that's what *domain objects* are about. If you perform calculations with them, they are no longer DTOs. Your domain in this case is financial calculations. Those objects should have a form that makes calculations as easy as possible.

Comment: To put it another way, you'd never model those classes on how the FIX protocol is structured.

Comment: No, you're correct! However I might've explained it badly; the values will be "remapped" into how our different engines expect them to be, or at least the data within these objects will be used as input to these calculations, but it's not a 1:1 mapping; the engines expect other models. Also, this is not a public API and it will only be used from other internal services. Does this still sound 'wrong'? Should I rethink how we transfer data? My initial plan was to have a library which defines the "transfer models" (DTOs?) and is used by the different services, is this bad practice? Thanks!